# WCF CreateMessage fails on escaped ASCII characters

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization, corewcf

I am migrating a WCF client application from DotNet Framework to DotNet (Core) 7.  The object I am using serializes using ASCII character 0x07 as a separator, which under DotNet Framework would be escaped to **&#x7;**.

```
var request = new Request(...);

Message wcfMessage = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, "MyServiceAction", request);

var wcfMessageXml = wcfMessage.ToString();
```

Under dotnet framework, this results in a WCF body that looks like <SerializedData>Field 1&#x7;Field 2&#x7;Etc<SerializedData>.

However, using the same code in dotnet core, I am getting: System.ArgumentException : '\a', hexadecimal value 0x07, is an invalid character.

I've tracked this down to the fact that in the latest dotnet, the XmlReader, XmlWriter, and related classes will try to unescape any escape sequences in text, and then check whether the character is valid XML.  If I were using those classes directly, I could use XmlReaderSetting/XmlWriterSettings.CheckCharacters = false to skip over this bad behavior, but I can't figure out how I can do the same with the WCF Message object.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: The Message class has an OnBeginWriteMessage  method which gets the XmlDictionaryWriter passed to it, in theory if you extended the Message class you could override the method and set CheckCharacters on this writer instance.

Comment: The XmlDictionaryWriter Class derives from XmlWriter and it can be added with `XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, CheckCharacters = false };`. Or you can try `Regex.Replace`.